# Transferring domain + eveyrthing + SSL EV(Extended Validation) certificate to another hosting provider. How to transfer SSL EV?

Tags: apache, unix, ssl, migration

I'm confused a little bit with my problem, so I don't know if I have to start the migration from the hosting provider #1 to the hosting provider #2 **(#1->#2)**.
Everything is good to migrate, but SSL EV certificate...

Now I'm on #1 (Unix/Apache, shared hosting plan) and have an SSL EV certificate.
I'm' thinking of moving to #2 (the same Unix/Apache, shared hosting plan), because of some reasons.
The problem is SSL EV certificate migration.

Could anybody explain me the process of transfering ov SSL EV certificate?

**Additional info:**
I was told by the customer representative from #2, that I have to request the CSR withing my AMP, then provide this to #1, so that #1 can provide me a Certificate that matches that key.

Customer representative from #1 says migration of SSL EV is not a very simple process and would highly recommend me to hire someone for help (but, I believe the reason could be to stop me from migration).
Can I do it on my own by following the instructions? Is that's too complicated? Do you know how to do that (to migrate with SSL EV for dummies)?
Both new and old hostings are shared hostings with Unix/Apache/MySQL.

So, is a migration of SSL EV certificate so complicated that it should stop me?

P.S. The project is not alilve right now, so I downloaded the files&db to my computer for future migration.

Is the process so complicated and expensive (to hire someone who can help -$500? $1000?), so it's easier to get a new SSL EV certificate (from the very beginning - $100..$300 + several days up to 2 weeks it took when I got one)?

Your recommendation is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: sorry, not a programming question, try http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. The next time I hope to be a bit smarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the CSR itself is useless, it's the private key you'll need. The public key in the CSR is the same as the public key in your EV certificate.

Overall, it depends on who actually owns that certificate. If your company owns that EV certificate (which you should really do, especially if it's an EV cert that's be assigned to your company), you could try to get hold of the private key (which you may already have) and transfer it across to your new hosting service.

However, since it's a shared host, and since #1 is likely to have had access to the private key, it may effectively be considered as compromised.
Some CAs might allow you to re-key your certs (i.e. revoke the current cert and re-issue a new one) within their package (so you may have to send the CA a newly generated CSR, but the overall process might be easier): this is something you must check with your CA.

There's nothing complicated about changing hosting provider. If you don't trust #1 enough not to have kept a copy of the private key (and depending on your security policies), you'll have to create a new CSR and get a new certificate anyway (in doubt, that's the most reasonable option). Whether the process can be simplified (and be cheaper) because you already have a valid certificate with that CA is a matter between your and your CA. It doesn't have much to do with #1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I trust #1 enough, no problems with that. The problem with their hosting service is they deliver emails not in time using mail() function - not immediately, sometimes it takes up to 30 minutes to deliver email. In some circumstances that's a poor quality of service.